# Iterate a for loop with an integer which is a part of a string

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing

I have a pandas data-frame with axes like Time[s], Time[s].1, Time[s].2 ans so on up to Time[s].30. I want to find out the column with the maximum resolution. For that I need to put those all in a for loop I think. As the name 'Time[s].x' is a string, I don't know how to iterate it from 0 to 30.

```
for i in df['Time[s]."Something to write here"]:
```

Sample Input dataframe: (The columns are till Time[s].30)

```
Time[s]     v1  Time[s].1   v2
160.84621   0   160.84808   7
161.14613   0   161.14802   7
```

Sample Output: `'Time[s]'` 
As the interval i.e `(df['Time[s]'][1] - df['Time[s]][0])` is less than
                      `(df['Time[s].1'][1] - df['Time[s].1][0])`.
 I need to check with all 30 columns.

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan please find the input and the desired output there.

Comment: @tworitdash - Do yo uthink columns names with max difference?

Comment: @jezrael yes, I needed the minimum difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
print (df)
     Time[s]  v1  Time[s].1  v2  Time[s].2  v3              Time[s].3  v4
0  160.84621   0  160.84808   7  168.84621   0              162.84808   7
1  161.14613   0  161.14802   7  170.14613   0              164.14802   7
2  163.12613   0  161.14852   7  170.64613   0  Disable this function   7
3  165.16613   0  161.14892   7  170.24613   0              160.14802   7

df1 = df.filter(like='Time').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).diff()
print (df1)
   Time[s]  Time[s].1  Time[s].2  Time[s].3
0      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1  0.29992    0.29994    1.29992    1.29994
2  1.98000    0.00050    0.50000        NaN
3  2.04000    0.00040   -0.40000        NaN

s = df1.idxmin(axis=1)
print (s)
0          NaN
1      Time[s]
2    Time[s].1
3    Time[s].2
dtype: object
```

**Explanation**:

1. First filter all columns with `Time` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)
2. Each column convert [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), parameter `errors='coerce'` means convert not numeric to `NaN`s
3. Get differences by [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)
4. Last get columns names by minimal values per rows by [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html)

Comment: I got a data type error at this line "`df = df.filter(like='Time').diff()`" . Erorr: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @tworitdash - How working `df.filter(like='Time').astype(float).diff()` ?

Comment: Got this one now. `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Disable this function'`

Comment: @tworitdash - It means there are string value `Disable this function` between numeric, I edit answer for replace these values to `NaN`s

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One quick question @jezrael : How can I set multiple index? indexing I want to do with all Time[s] columns.

Comment: @tworitdash - Do you think `df = df.set_index(df.filter(like='Time').columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks